# find a maximal dimension subspace of a vector space in which quadratic form is nondegenerate

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, trace, bilinear-form

Let $V := M_2(\mathbb{R})$ and let function $f : V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$$f \left( A, B \right) = 2 \mbox{tr} \left( A B \right) -\mbox{tr} \left( A \right) \mbox{tr} \left( B \right)$$

I showed that it is a bilinear form on $V$ and I found that the rank of its quadratic form $q$ is $3$, and the sign is $(3,0)$ in that way:

$$q\left(A\right)=f\left(A,A\right)=2tr\left(A^2\right)-tr\left(A\right)tr\left(A\right)=2\left(a_{11}^2+2a_{12}a_{21}+a_{22}^2\right)-\left(a_{11}+a_{22}\right)^2$$
The next exercise is to find a subspace of $V$ of maximal dimension that $q|_W$ is nondegenerate.

Comment: wait. The bilinear form has dimension $4\times 4$. How can the rank be 9?

Comment: sorry, I solve by mistake he case for $M_3(R)$ by the case is $M_2(R)$ and I modified now the result for it. I guess the technique and the observation for finding the maximal subspace will be good for both cases.

Comment: How did you find the rank? If you've already found the 3 nontrivial eigenvectors just take the span of those guys.

Comment: I've found the trace of $A^2$, and wrote the whole $q = f(A,A)$  equation in terms of $a_11, a_12, a_21, a_22$, it is pretty simple.How do I prove that this is the maximal subspace ? 
What is the explanation to it ?
Added it in the question.